# Caching result of Fragment.findNavController()?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

In code samples I always see that `findNavController()` is called again and again / used locally instead of storing it in a class variable.

Is there any specific reason for it? Is it a bad idea to cache the `NavController` found by `findNavController()`? Or is the call so cheap that it doesn't matter? I am wondering because one tends to cache `findViewById(...)` calls, but not `findNavController()`

Comment: NavControllers are stateful, and after `onSaveInstanceState` they might start ignoring your commands.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Do you might want to post a answer with more details on this?